# Change encrypted data prefix of the Transit secret engine

Tags: hashicorp-vault

[The transit secrets engine](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/transit) returns encrypted data with a prefix:

% vault write transit/encrypt/my-key plaintext=$(base64 <<< "my secret data")
Key            Value

---

ciphertext     vault:v1:C7BqsulaJTww6+zyO+0TnjFUUdDVTQWIatlbxOtEkZbF5govTZAp8S6gjQ==

Is there any way of customazation where we can change vault:v1: >>>> CMPname:APP:

```
vault:v2:VHTTBb2EyyNYHsa3XiXsvXOQSLKulH+NqS4eRZdtc2TwQCxqJ7PUipvqQ==
```

So that it becomes:

```
CompnanyName:appV1:0VHTTBb2EyyNYHsa3XiXsvXOQSLKulH+NqS4eRZdtc2TwQCxqJ7PUipvqQ==
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Using capital letters often reads as someone shouting. Stick to lower case, as using capital letters could have the effect of *reducing* the interest in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Vault has a [default version template](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/main/sdk/helper/keysutil/policy.go#L70) that evaluates to `vault:v{{version}}`. There is [code that support a custom version template](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/main/sdk/helper/keysutil/policy.go#L1575-L1590), but [the `version_template` parameter is ignored when you create the key](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/main/builtin/logical/transit/path_keys.go#L145-L154).

So as of today, this option does not exist, sorry.

This metadata is not encrypted (nor signed). I suggest you either add a prefix to it:

```
CompnanyName:app:vault:v1:0VHTTBb2EyyNYHsa3XiXsvXOQSLKulH+NqS4eRZdtc2TwQCxqJ7PUipvqQ=
```

Or replace it:

```
CompnanyName:app:v1:0VHTTBb2EyyNYHsa3XiXsvXOQSLKulH+NqS4eRZdtc2TwQCxqJ7PUipvqQ=
```

To be future proof (so that you can remove your custom code and use `version_template` one day), I suggest that you keep a link between `my-key` (the name of the key) and the prefix. As the code stands today, it is unlikely that Vault will support multiple prefixes for a single key name.